# json schema date-time does not check correctly

Tags: json, datetime, jsonschema

I have a JSON and a JSON-schema

JSON:

```
{
"aaa": "4000-02-01 00:00:00"
}
```

JSON-schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {

        "aaa": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }


    }, "required": ["aaa"]
}
```

The JSON gets validated by the JSON-schema. However if I change the field `aaa` to "bla" the schema does not notice that it is not a date-time any longer.

Did I miss anything in the schema?

Comment: What [software](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) are you using to process the validation? Because some software are buggy or do not implements everything.. even the specification (draft 04) says that date-time format SHOULD be implemented: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor106

Comment: Some packages optionally implement format validation.  tv4 for nodejs lets you add validations for the formats via a function call.  Maybe other libraries at least have this feature?

Answer (score 53):

For Python's [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) library, specify the format checker when calling `validate`:

```python
jsonschema.validate(data, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```

To validate a date-time format, the [strict-rfc3339](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/strict-rfc3339/) package should be installed.

See [Validating Formats](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/#validating-formats).

Comment: Thanks! Because I am a Python newbie it took longer than it should for me to realise you can `pip install strict-rfc3339`. Anyway, works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a way to use `format_checker` argument with `iter_errors`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You should be able to use `format_checker` when you instantiate the validator.  For example: `validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker()); validator.iter_errors(document)`.

Answer (score 10):

Validation with `"format"` is optional.  This is partly because schema authors are allowed to completely make up new formats, so expecting all formats to be validated is not reasonable.

Your library *should* (if it is decent) have a way to register custom validators for particular formats.  For example, the `tv4` validation library (in JavaScript) has the [`tv4.addFormat()` method](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4#addformatformat-validationfunction):

```
tv4.addFormat('date-time', function (data) {
    return isValidDate(data);
});
```

Once you've done this, then `"format": "date-time"` in the schema should validate dates correctly.

Comment: Hum.. According to the [specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor106) format and also **date-time format** implementation are **not optional**.. They SHOULD be implemented.. Concerning tv4, it's probably an [oversight](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/search?q=date-time&ref=cmdform)?

Comment: Right where you linked, it first says "Implementations **MAY** support the "format" keyword. Should they choose to do so...".  So it's a MAY for supporting "format" at all - but if you do, then you SHOULD support the standard set.

Comment: Out-of-the-box, tv4 doesn't support any "format" values at all.  However, the project is definitely looking for a standard set of "format" validators, so you could help out if you like. :)

Comment: Yep but you agree that tv4 definitely supports the format keyword so: "[they SHOULD implement validation for attributes defined below](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor106)" (date-time). Yep tv4 documentation says that "[There are no built-in format validators](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4#addformatformat-validationfunction)". I'm gonna make my own validators and maybe submit them to tv4 project :)

Comment: +1 for writing/submitting a set of validators for the standard set.

Comment: @cloudfeet I tried use `addFormat` but seems not execute, always get the error `ValidationError: Invalid type: string (expected newformatname)`  would you see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105527/how-to-allow-nan-as-number-with-tv4-validate, do I miss something?

Answer (score 8):

It is highly likely that the implementation of JSON schema validation that you're using is requiring the `T` separator between the date and time components.  This is a staple of the [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) spec and [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which it is based upon.  While both have provisions for omitting the `T`, they both make it something that can be done by agreement, rather then a mandatory thing to support.  (Go figure.)

Also, RFC3339 *does* require that you include either a time zone offset or a `Z` to indicate UTC.  This locks it down to a particular moment in time, rather than a human representation of one in some unknown time zone.  Since you have required neither, that's likely while it has failed validation.

From the [JSON Schema spec](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor108):

> **7.3.1.2.  Validation**
>
> A string instance is valid against this attribute if it is a valid date representation as defined by **RFC 3339, section 5.6** [RFC3339].

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround by using [this library](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting). It checks the content of the field in javascript code:

```
function isValidDate(datestring) {

    var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    var date = format.parse(datestring);  
    if (date) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which is weird given that it should have a timezone offset no?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, if you change `"aaa"` to `"bla"` you are adding a new property that is not defined and hence the schema will only validate `"aaa"`. If you do not want to add properties I believe you should add `"additionalProperties": false`. Example below:

Here the schema states that `"aaa"` is the only property and its values should be in date-time.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {

        "aaa": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }


    }, "required": ["aaa"]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the source code  for the python jsonschema module.

Find the datetime-related code, at `jsonschema/_format.py` func  `is_date_time(instance)`. Like this, about line 204 - 225, for version 2.6.0:

```
try:
    import strict_rfc3339
except ImportError:
    try:
        import isodate
    except ImportError:
        pass
    else:
        @_checks_drafts("date-time", raises=(ValueError, isodate.ISO8601Error))
        def is_datetime(instance):
            if not isinstance(instance, str_types):
                return True
            return isodate.parse_datetime(instance)
else:
    @_checks_drafts("date-time")
    def is_datetime(instance):
        if not isinstance(instance, str_types):
            return True
        return strict_rfc3339.validate_rfc3339(instance)
```

Comment out the above and paste this, or replace the `_check_drafts` function above with this:

```
@_checks_drafts("date-time")
def is_datetime(instance):
    if not isinstance(instance, str_types):
        return True
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(instance, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: pls tell me where, I can't find it. Thank you~~

Comment: @CodeCaster No, they have an English translation, followed by a Chinese translation underneath it.