# Validating Javascript Objects containing dates

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema

What is a good practise to validate a JavaScript Object which contains date fields?

There are JSON validators like tv4 which can [validate the format of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264146/json-schema-date-time-does-not-check-correctly).

However, our business logic works with dates of instance JavaScript-Date, and these objects won't validate.

Our current procedure is

1. Read *business* object with JSON.parse() using a [date reviver](https://gist.github.com/jcbozonier/1692807)
2. Process the object with business logic, then validate with
3. Convert the object to JSON with a [date stringifier](http://www.json.org/js.html)
4. Read string back with JSON.parse(), now without reviver
5. Validate this object

Is there a better way to validate opposed to steps 3, 4 and 5?
Preferably validating the *business* object directly?

Example:

The JSON string

```
{
    "birth": "1994-03-17"
}
```

Schema for the JSON string

```
{
    type: 'string',
    format: 'date-time'
}
```

The *business* object

```
{
    birth: new Date("1994-03-17")
}
```

Comment: if(businessobject['birth'] instanceof Date)

Comment: Yes, this is what the validator should do. In addition to validating tons of other, non-date fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the tv4 library you can do:

```
tv4.addFormat('date-time', function (data) {
    if (data instaceof Date) return null;
    else return "not a valid date";
});
```

and your validation should be:

```
{
    type: "object",
    format: "date-time"
}
```

This method is mentioned in the question you posted ([json schema date-time does not check correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264146/json-schema-date-time-does-not-check-correctly))

Comment: Oh why didn't I spot the trick changing the type to object! Let me check with our codebase ...