# JSON query: date time validation in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, validation, schema

I have a JSON data which is getting generated through python scripts as below.

JSON:

```
{
"name":"abc"
"insrt_dt": datetime.datetime(2020,12,15,18,35,30,31547}
"demand_dt": Timestamp('2014-05-09 00:00:00')
}
```

---

I want to do schema validation before inserting it into Mongo database.

I am able to handle "***name***" field , but not able to handle ***"insrt_dt"*** & "***demand_d***t" fields.
for name: it is working as per syntax.

[json schema date-time does not check correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264146/json-schema-date-time-does-not-check-correctly).

but unable to decide type and format for ***"insrt_dt" & "demand_dt"***

Comment: can you show schema whith exists?

Comment: Did you mean to enter some code for *`enter code here`*?

Answer (score 0):

the JSON needs to be correctly formatted. In particular, missing commas.
also the `datetime` line was closed with } and should be ).

see:  https://json.org/example.html

The correct JSON should look like this:

```
{
"name":"abc",
"insrt_dt": datetime.datetime(2020,12,15,18,35,30,31547),
"demand_dt": Timestamp('2014-05-09 00:00:00')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  const { Schema } = mongoose;

  const blogSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    insrt_dt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    demand_dt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  });
```

// is Timestamp('2014-05-09 00:00:00') number ?